# NDK update error for opensl

Tags: android, audio, android-ndk, opensl

I am facing some problem with compiling the code, After updating the project, now i am getting build field with error.

```
Error:(81) Android NDK: Application targets deprecated ABI(s): armeabi mips mips64.
Error:(82) Android NDK: Support for these ABIs will be removed in a future NDK release.
```

In my code i have listed the `APP_ABI := all` like this.

Answer (score 0):

Just change to

```
APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a arm64-v8a x86
```

to use only actual architectures.

Comment: should i be using this in Application.mk file ?

Comment: Yes, you can use it in `Application.mk`

Comment: Also to just work on all the devices on market, just `APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a` is sufficient

Comment: Thank you Anton. are you familiar with Android ?

Comment: np, more or less familiar :) please accept the answer if it worked for you

Comment: With the same errors or others? Feel free to post all the error log

Comment: Better yet, remove the line entirely.

Comment: Also it's harmful to your app to exclude the other architectures. Aside from the fact that there are a non-trivial number of Intel devices out there, there's a pretty significant performance (and therefore battery) improvement from arm64.

Comment: @DanAlbert I've included arm64, not much improvement over armeabi-v7a though